# Typescript get value from one type to another if the field value is true

Tags: typescript

Let's say that I have two objects:

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'anything here',
  b: 12323,
  c: {
    d: 'ashdajd'
  }
}

const object2 = {
  a: true,
  c: true
}
```

I want to pick all fields from `object1` where on `object2` they are set to true.

I was trying a bunch of different things, but I couldn't get this to work. Basically I want a generic function that you pass these 2 objects (the second object should only have fields from the first object) and returns the true fields from the second object but with the value of the first one.

So, using the objects above, this would be:

```js
const getIntersection = <T>(first: T, second: {[key in keyof T]?: boolean}): ReturnTypeHere => {
  // here I can just loop the second keys and get the values from the first one
}

const result = getIntersection(object1, object2);

// The TYPE (and also the value) should be a const object:
// {a: 'anything here', c: { d: 'ashdajd' }}
```

Just to give more context, I'm trying to create a function to compute some react native styles based on conditions, similar to the `classname` lib for react. So I implemented this function:

```js
export const computeStyles = <
  T extends NamedStyles<T> | NamedStyles<any>,
  U extends keyof T,
>(
  styles: T,
): ((conditions: { [key in U]?: boolean }) => {
  [key in U]?: T[key];
}) => {
  const computed: { [key in U]?: T[key] } = {};

  return (conditions) => {
    for (const key in conditions) {
      if (conditions[key]) {
        computed[key] = styles[key];
      }
    }

    return computed;
  };
};
```

The problem is that the type of the returned object is the same as T.

```js
const test = computeStyles({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.white.main,
    width: '100%',
    height: props.multiline ? 150 : 46,
    borderRadius: 4,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    paddingVertical: 14,
  },
  containerError: {
    borderColor: theme.palette.error.main,
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
  text: {
    ...theme.typography.body1,
    color: theme.palette.black.main,
  },
})({
  container: true,
});
```

and the returned type:

```js
const test: {
    container?: {
        backgroundColor: string;
        width: string;
        height: number;
        borderRadius: number;
        paddingHorizontal: number;
        paddingVertical: number;
    };
    containerError?: {
        borderColor: string;
        borderWidth: number;
    };
    text?: {
        ...;
    };
}
```

Maybe this is not possible since I need to check the actual value of the field of the second parameter, but I'm not sure

Comment: Could you clarify your last sentence there? "I need to check the actual value of the field of the second parameter" – does this mean that the second parameter will be determined dynamically, rather than specified as a literal?

Comment: @motto The second parameter will be dynamic, instead of declaring all the fields that I want, I'm going to pass probably all fields and the values will be a inline conditions, like this:

```typescript
const test = computeStyles({ ... })({
    container: variableHere === 'shouldUseContainer',
    error: hasError,
    success: !hasError && success
});
```

So yeah, it will be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

By using `Object.entries(obj2)`, you can return an `Object` to `[[key, value]...]`.
After that, through `Array.prototype.filter()` find a true key and return it.

```
const computeStyles = <
  T,
  U extends keyof T,
>(
  styles: T,
  conditions: { [key in U]?: boolean }
): Pick<T, U> => {
  return Object.entries(conditions)
    .filter(([key, value]) => value && !!styles?.[key])
    .reduce((acc, [key, _]) => {
      acc[key] = styles[key]

      return acc
    }, {} as Pick<T, U>)
}

console.log(computeStyles(object1, object2))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but this does not solve the main problem, wich is the response type including all fields of `BooleanNames` instead of just the fields that are `true`. Also, the `object2` will be dynamic, meaning that I'll use other variables to define the fields for `object2`. Take a look at my comment in the question, you'll see what I mean

Comment: I edited code, the key is taken from `U` and the value is taken from `T`. am i right?